# How to integrate the ofbiz erp order invoice details for accounting in dot net

Tags: .net, ofbiz

I need the details about how to intergrate the ofbiz erp of order invoice details for accounting in dot net.

Answer (score 1):

you can export the entity 'invoice_item' which relates to 'invoice' on a regular basis.

Regards,
Hans

http://antwebsystems.com: the quality Apache OFBiz support and training provider with competitive rates